# Detect inverted screen in Cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, accessibility

How can I detect if the screen is inverted on at least iOS in Cordova? More specifically I’m looking to support the iOS 11 “smart invert” feature, however it doesn’t matter if this “invert detection” is also triggered by the “classic invert.”

> I’ve seen the phonegap accessibility plugin, but I don’t see how to utilize it for this case without simply setting an interval to check it over and over again, which seems like too much of a hack to me. I’m looking for an event-based approach if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Reading further, I missed the fact that [the `phonegap-mobile-accessibility` plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-mobile-accessibility/blob/master/README.md) has events that you can listen to, including for invert colors. As such, using this plugin, you can bind an event as shown below:

```
window.addEventListener(
    MobileAccessibilityNotifications.INVERT_COLORS_STATUS_CHANGED,
    info => { // info.isInvertColorsEnabled });
```

As well, you can check the status at any time (e.g. on page load) like so:

```
MobileAccessibility.isInvertColorsEnabled(
    b => { // typeof b == “boolean” });
```